# Click on input does not focus in IE 10, needs to click twice

Tags: internet-explorer, input, click, focus, mouse

So here is my code :

`<label class="control-label" for="pagecreate-title">Page Title</label>
<input type="text" id="pagecreate-title" maxlength="255">`

The issue is simple, when you click on the input (no javascript, purely with the mouse), you can see the focus but it disappears after and you have to click another time to get the focus.

Clicking the label does trigger the focus properly... I wonder if having the label is the issue...

This happens for IE10 but also until IE7.

Any ideas how to fix this without ugly code ? Many thanks.

Comment: I couldn't replicate your bug. Do you have any javascript on the page at all?

Comment: I have some javascript but nothing bound to the label/input on first render. I made sure of that. I think it is the way this code is rendered (backbone view + twig) that could lead to this issue. I will continue my investigation but whatever this is, it works on every browsers except IE10.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? I am experiencing pretty much the same affliction, but on IE11.

Comment: @Yoshiya I don't recall finding a solution I'm afraid...